# Common method uses unknown object type java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface

I am writing some java code and I am unsure of what structure I should use.  I have different classes that each contain a populate method which receives a line of text from a text file. The contents of the text file are specific to the class. I need to modify the method (shown below) so that it reads the specific text file, and then populates the proper class(object) with data from the text file. The method that reads the text file (shown below) is the same regardless of the unknown object it will be populating, except for the object type.

```
Public Class ReceivesMyTextFile{
    /*This class receives my text file and does some other stuff. */

    /*Common method.  I do not want to put this readData method, which is 
      the same except one line of code, into each of my UnknownUntilRunTime 
      classes. */
    public void readData(File inFile){

        /* the contents of inFile determine which UnknownUntilRunTime class
          to instantiate, and then call its populate method in the loop. */

        /* I do not want to instantiate this object in the loop, but I can't 
           do it here either because I don't know what type it is yet. */
        UnknownUntilRunTime unknownObject = new UnknownUntilRunTime();

        //TextFileReader handles reading one line of text at a time using 
        //BufferedReader class.
        TextFileReader tfr = new TextFileReader(inFile.getPath());

        String currentRecord = tfr.getNextLine();
        while(tfr.hasData()){
            currentRecord = currentRecord.trim();

            //This is the problem.  I don't know this object until run-time
            //The contents of inFile determines the object type.
            //this is the only line of code different.
            unknownObject.populate(currentLine);

            currentRecord = tfr.getNextLine();
        }
    }
}

Public Class UnknownUntilRunTime{
    /* this class represents one of many different types of products.  
       this class is unknown until the contents of the correlating text file 
       are read. */


    public void populate(String currentLine){ 

        //populate this object with data from each currentLine of text. 

    }
}
```

My question is how should I go about organizing my code to call this common method, without knowing the the object type?  Maybe I should do this in a different way?  Is this an example of using inheritance, or an interface, or generics?  I'm just not sure how to proceed.  Any advice with an example would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: It feels like maybe a factory or a Strategy Pattern could be used here, but without more details it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: What additional details do you need?

Comment: Pretty much everything, I think.

Comment: did you try generics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is how should I go about organizing my code to call this
>   common method, without knowing the the object type?

You have multiple kinds of object that should have a `populate()` method with a `String` as parameter.
An interface with a `populate(String)` method should suit your need.

Declare an interface : `Populatable` and make objects that should be populated implementations of `Populatable`.

```
public interface Populatable{   
  void populate(String line);
}
```

An implementation :

```
public MyObject implements Populatable{
     public void populate(String line){
          // do task...
     }
}
```

And you can use them in your method now :

```
 // you declare the interface as declared type and the chosen implementation 
 // is determined at runtime according to your requirements
Populatable populatable = ...; 

while(tfr.hasData()){
    currentRecord = tfr.getNextLine();
    currentRecord = currentRecord.trim();
    populatable.populate(currentLine);
}
```

PS : I have reversed the order of instructions as it seems not logical to trim the record before getting it.

Comment: Thank You!  This is exactly what i needed!